# Is there a way reformat code in FlashDevelop?

Tags: flashdevelop, hotkeys

Is there a way to reformat code, i.e. force correct indentation in FlashDevelop as you can do with CTRL-SHIFT-F in Eclipse?

Answer (score -8, accepted):

open netbeans 6.5, create an xml file and then paste your mxml code; right click, format code, finally copy this formatted text from netbeans and past it in flex builder. it´s all.... i hope to be usefull

Answer (score 12):

Since FlashDevelop 4 there is a reformater included: press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>

Comment: More annoying than useful (to me) unfortunately.

Comment: Only sometimes annoying because of bugs and missing features. But better than no auto-formatter. And can be changed to Ctrl+Shift+F (what I have done myself).

Comment: Thanks, though not format html and JavaScript codes.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin for FlashDevelop worked for me:

http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=5208